# Am I misunderstanding something about Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, routes

Here is a test I wrote:

```
[Test]
public void Can_Generate_Links_To_Other_Pages()
{
    //Arrange: We're going to extend the Html helper class.
    //It doesn't matter if the variable we use is null            
    HtmlHelper html = null;

    PagingInfo pagingInfo = new PagingInfo(){
        CurrentPage = 2,
        TotalItems = 28,
        ItemsPerPage = 10
    };

    Func<int, String> pageUrl = i => "Page" + i;

    //Act: Here's how it should format the links.
    MvcHtmlString result = html.PageLinks(pagingInfo, pageUrl);

    //Assert:
    result.ToString().ShouldEqual(@"<a href=""Page1"">1</a><a class=""selected"" href=""Page2"">2</a><a href=""Page3"">3</a>");
}
```

Please note how I'm hard coding the way the links should look like, which I think is a good idea for a test to do because that way if it doesn't look how I envision it, the test would fail.

I understand **why** this test works, after all my route in global.asax.cs is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Page{page}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "List" }
);
```

Great - but now if I change that route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "page/{page}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "List" }
);
```

The URL's change, as expected, right? **But the test still passes.** Since I hard coded the way the url should look like in the test, it's in my understanding that the test should fail, correct?

Am I missing something?

I've already Cleaned the project and rebuilt it using the new route but the test still passes.

I'm really curious about this, thanks!

Comment: PageLinks is part of MVC? Or is it aftermarket code, perhaps from Pro ASP.NET MVC 2? I agree that something looks off here.

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests should eliminate dependencies. ASP.NET's routing is your dependency in this case - you shouldn't make it one. I'm not exactly sure what is happening in `PageLinks`, but if its just taking that model class and generating the HTML, then I say its doing its job properly if the test passes.

Comment: But, why is the test passing? The returned URLs are: page/3 - page/4 - page/5 | But the hard coded strings are page3 - page4 - page5. It doesn't make sense. :P

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of thing I typically don't bother to unit test. I find that manual testing, or something like a Coded UI Test is better at this sort of thing - send a user to determine whether a user interface is working.

Comment: Selenium would be a good choice for functional testing. Users are flaky. Selenium isn't.

Answer (score 2):

are you missing `Assert.That(...)` wrap around your last line?

Comment: He probably is using the BDD style syntax where you can have extension method to create a more natural flow of asserting the condition. So .ShouldEqual(something) under the hood uses AssertEquals or AssertThat